# Importing Spring properties files from jar file on classpath

Tags: java, spring

I want to import all property files, ending on `.properties` that are contained in the `src/main/resource` locations of **ALL** jar-dependencies my project has.

I wrote a JUnit test, where my context.xml is located in the src/test/resources folder. I specified the property-placeholder using wildcards, but it doesn't work.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>
```

May be I am to stupid, but I could not find a solution to my problem on the net. Does anyone here know what is the correct syntax?

**EDIT:**

The root project, has maven dependencies, that are resolved from my workspace:

[image]

And i want to import the module.properties files of the dependent projects:

[image]

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do that in Spring. The xsd for location specifically states "The location of the properties file to resolve placeholders against, as a Spring
 resource location: a URL, a "classpath:" pseudo URL, or a relative file path.
 Multiple locations may be specified, separated by commas. If neither location nor properties-ref is
 specified, placeholders will be resolved against system properties"

Comment: <context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/DevPa/test/dev-external.properties"/> have you tried with this

Comment: @DevPa Wouldn't that add a problematic dependency on the filesystem location? Is it possible to express it as a relative path?

Comment: In theory that should work. The location is parsed as a `String[]` and passed into the `locations` field of the selected placeholder. This `locations` field takes a `Resource[]` as argument. The `String[]` will be converted to a `Resource[]` by the `ResourceArrayPropertyEditor` which is perfectly capable of handling `classpath*:*.properties`. Your properties files are in the root of `src/main/resources`?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes they are in src/main/resources, BUT in an external jar-file, that i added to my classpath. It might be relevant that my context.xml is in the src/test/resources location ..

Comment: They are in `src/main/resources` and not in `src\main\resources\some-dir`? Also is this jar available on your test classpath? How have you added it to your classpath?

Comment: @M.Deinum The path is src/main/resources/module.properties and I added it to my classpath as an eclipse project. See my updated question.

Comment: You should add it as a maven dependency currently you are mixing maven and eclipse local dependencies (from what I remember that is trouble waiting to happen). If the project is in your local workspace the eclipse maven integration should be able to pick it up. If you already have a maven dependency for this project that is probably overriding the stuff that is in your local workspace, meaning no `modules.properties` as that appears to be a new file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-classpath-wildcards):

> The " classpath*:" prefix can also be combined with a PathMatcher pattern in the rest of the location path, for example " classpath*:META-INF/*-beans.xml". [...]

But there is a restriction:

> Please note that " classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the pattern starts, unless the actual target files reside in the file system. This means that a pattern like " classpath*:*.xml" will not retrieve files from the root of jar files but rather only from the root of expanded directories. [...]

So if I place my module's property files in src/main/resources/META-INF, I can load of them as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:/META-INF/*.properties" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it sth like this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>classpath*:your.properties</value>
                    <value>classpath*:your.properties</value>
                     .....
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        </bean>
```

more complex example:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:properties/defaults.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:properties/${props.env.name}.properties</value>

            <value>classpath*:com/calciuum/config/defaults.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:com/calciuum/config/${props.env.name}.properties</value>

            <value>classpath*:${props.env.classpath}/defaults.properties</value>
            <value>classpath*:${props.env.classpath}/${props.env.name}.properties</value>

            <value>file:${props.env.ext.properties}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

if the properties that you are using is less than 4. You can use this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test1.properties,classpath:test2.properties" />
```

Else use this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" />
```